# Problem with Left Outer Join In crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I have the following informations and i want to generate an attendance report per day.I will explain the concept

EMP Table
ID   NAME
1     Hassan

2     Hussain

3     Hameed

4     Cruz

5     Philip

Transaction table

EmpID          Time

1              5/8/2010 8:00 AM

2              5/8/2010 9:00 AM

3              5/8/2010 10:00 AM

My Attendance Report should look like this

Date:5/8/2010

ID  NAME      STATUS

1     Hassan   Present

2     Hussain  Present

3     Hameed  Present

4     Cruz       Absent

5     Philip      Absent

I tried  the following ,

1.Created a link wth left outer join ,EMP.ID->transcatio.EmpID

2.Group by date from transation table

1. Created aformula for status,looks like this

If IsNull({transaction.EmpID}) then 'Absent' else 'Present'

But the report displays only those employees,having transactions on that date.
The report looks like this,

ID NAME     STATUS

1   Hassan    Present

2   Hussain   Present

3   Hammed    Present
It seeems that,the left outer join didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the actual SQL query that was generated?  Go to Database-->Show SQL Query to see it.  It may also be helpful to not use a group by date and see what shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Try a right outer join using the same information that will tell you that it did it in the opposite direction of what you wanted.

Have you set the join to be enforced?  [Stack Overflow Enforced Link Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122975/what-is-the-benefit-of-enforce-join-option-in-crystal-reports)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to join two tables in crystal report with left out join and at the same time want to filter report based on right table e.g. ORDER.ORDER_DATE>='1-JAN-2014' the join will be converted to equi join
to solve the problem some people suggest to use
(ISNULL(ORDER.ORDER_DATE) OR ORDER.RDER_DATE>='1-JAN-2014')

The above solution only works when there are 0 orders for customer and you still want to show those custer but what if some customer have more than 0 orders and orders date is ON or BEFORE  '31-DEC-2013'. In such situation ISNULL(ORDER.ORDER_DATE) will not work. to solve such problem you need to  either add command object or create a view for orders table as following

1. Create command object with following sql
         Select Customer.customer_name,Order.Order_id, order.order_date
         from customer left outer join order on customer.customer_id=order.Customer_id and order.order_date>='1-JAN-2014'
2. second solution is to create a view for orders as
    create or replace view view_orderrs as
    Select * from oders where order.order_dt>='1-JAN-2014'
   and then use the view in the report instead of order table as the right table.