# Crystal Reports XI - Group not returned when adding field which might be null

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm a very new user of Crystal Reports with no training but with a very light background in programming.

I have been working on a report which should show me some information regarding the order status of parts within my company. I have modified an existing report which had a lot of the information I was looking for and have added several fields containing more information I want to look up (information like stock, delivery date, suppliers and partnumbers). I have one last field I want to add to the report, which shows me the name of the supplier where the part is ordered.

**Problem:**
When I add this field in the report, the groups where there is no information for this field disappear. When I remove the same field again, the missing groups return.

I have tried to look everywhere for an option or function which suppresses a group when a field is null but can not find anything. I also have tried to add an isNull function to return a certain value when the field is empty, but with no results. Unfortunately I can't review the returned values because the group has disappeared when I add the field.

This problem might have to do with the fact I started working from an existing report, but I have not been able to find a reason to believe so.

**Update**
I have made some pictures showing the problematic result and the SQL-Query (I can only link to the folder in Onedrive because I'm not allowed to post more than two links at the same time):
http://1drv.ms/1J1enHj

Comment: how many tables are there in your report? is that field (name of the supplier) related to other table?

Comment: Looks like problem of linking tables.... check the query before adding last filed and after adding last field

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: heringer
There are 7 database fields in my report. The field needed is linked in the exact same way as another file which is working fine.

Siva
I have checked the SQL-query, and it returns the same value in both cases, except for the addition of the field mentioned.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find your solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122975/what-is-the-benefit-of-enforce-join-option-in-crystal-reports) because it's linking problem

Comment: I have tried every option given in the enforce join options with the link which is used by the field I'm trying to add. It does not seem to solve the problem but when set to anything else than "not enforced" the same effect where a couple of the entries disappear happens, even when not adding the field!